# Linq Join when second table will have multiple records

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join

Trying to create a Linq query that can do multiple searches in one command instead of having multiple search result pages.  It is working great when I am trying to find multiple records that have a subject (in my case CHIEF_COMPLAINT) and comments with a specific word.  The problem is when I want to search with serial numbers.

There are two issues here.  One is that multiple pieces of equipment can be attached to a specific ticket and also a single piece of equipment can be associated with multiple tickets.  When I query the table used to associate equipment to tickets (VIEW_WT_EQUIP, using the view because it is where the serial number is seen) I potential get multiple results with the same Ticket_ID.

This is the query that I have right now, but it returns no results when I put in a serial number that I know is in the system.

```
var query = from a in db.VIEW_WT_HEADERs
                    join c in db.VIEW_WT_EQUIPs on a.TICKET_ID equals c.TICKET_NUMBER into c_group
                    from c2 in c_group
                    join b in db.WT_EVENTs on a.TICKET_ID equals b.TICKET_ID
                    where b.COMMENTS.Contains(input) || a.CHIEF_COMPLAINT.Contains(input) || c2.SERIAL_NUMBER.Contains(input)
                    orderby a.TICKET_ID descending
                    select new { a.TICKET_ID, a.ENTRY_DATE, a.CONTACT, a.CHIEF_COMPLAINT, a.STATUS };
```

I also tried a method where I used 2 linq queries and put all the ticket numbers from a serial number search into a list, but the second query didn't like that I was trying to compare an int array.

I think I am just going about this wrong.  Join is probably not the right way to do this, but I don't know how to tell the main query to pull all the tickets associated with a piece of equipment.

Please let me know where I can clarify, because I know this explination is rough.

Answer (score 2):

I would put this as comment instead of an answer, but I want to show you some code, so I had to choose "answer".

If you are using Linq to Entities, you probably have a relationship between the objects. It means that the `join` is not necessary. You should only use join when no navigation property is available.

I can't tell exactly what you should do, but here is some code the might be helpful:

```
var query = from a in db.VIEW_WT_HEADERs
            from b in a.WT_EVENTs
            from c in a.VIEW_WT_EQUIPs 
            where b.COMMENTS.Contains(input) || a.CHIEF_COMPLAINT.Contains(input) ...
            orderby a.TICKET_ID descending
            select new { a.TICKET_ID, a.ENTRY_DATE, a.CONTACT, a.CHIEF_COMPLAINT, a.STATUS };
```

you can also use `let` to store a sub-expression:

```
var query = from a in db.VIEW_WT_HEADERs
            from b in a.WT_EVENTs
            from c in a.VIEW_WT_EQUIPs 
            let x = c.FirstOrDefault()
            where b.COMMENTS.Contains(input) || a.CHIEF_COMPLAINT.Contains(input) || x.SomeProperty ....
            orderby a.TICKET_ID descending
            select new { a.TICKET_ID, a.ENTRY_DATE, a.CONTACT, a.CHIEF_COMPLAINT, a.STATUS };
```

Those are just example, maybe it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will work in my DataClasses file and try to improve my Linq set up.  The only problem with the suggestion you gave is the FirstOrDefault().  It actually may be correct, but I would be worried if the piece of equipment appears on multiple tickets.  So if I say x.SERIAL_NUMBER.Contains(input) it will only show the first one it finds.  I guess if I could do (x.SERIAL_NUMBER.Contains(input) && x.TICKET_ID != x.TICKET_ID).  Ugh, that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: So, instead of FirstOrDefault, you could use Any(). Like `x.Any(i => i.Serial_Number.Contains(something))`

Comment: Keeps telling me that my VIEW doesn't have a definition for Any.

Comment: you should re-write your question, try be straight. It is very hard to understand what you need and what is your problem